# Error: EPERM : Operation not permitted,mkdir

Tags: reactjs, terminal, hyper

When i try to execute the command "npx create-react-app my-app"
Hyper shows error Error:EPERM : Operation not permitted, mkdir
comman not found : create react app.
Please help me to solve this problem.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
npm install -g create-react-app
```